# Avoid automatic ${role_default-roles-} assignment to a user in Keycloak

Tags: keycloak

I use keycloak v 16.1.1

At some point I started to notice that there is a role (which not actually a role entiity) that is automatically assigned to each user created in keycloak:

[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCuEb.png)

When I find this role in role list it turned out that it cannot be deleted:

[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGZEt.png)

And when I click on it it doesn't open this role view, it opens "Default roles" tab on the same page:

[screenshot3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlDED.png)

Could someone please help, how to avoid the automatic assignment of this veird role to each user.

P.S. Adding some real roles to "Default roles" doesn't solve the issue, everything is still the same as on screenshot1.

P.P.S Deleting via rest API return ther following error:
`"errorMessage": "default-roles-gmp is default role of the realm and cannot be removed."`

Comment: From what I understand, you cannot delete and stop the automatic assignment of the default role, but I found that you can remove it using rest api call https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/15.0/rest-api/index.html#_users_resource . But what is the issue with this role being associated to users ? If you can share your concern it would be helpful

Comment: @Umakanth thank you for your response. The problem is that client doen't want to see this role on UI. And we retrieve role representations from Keycloak directly. I will try rest API, but we previously tried to remove it via Dabatbase directly but keycloak failed on startup after that.

Comment: @Umakanth Deleting it via REST API causes the following message `"errorMessage": "default-roles-gmp is default role of the realm and cannot be removed."`